# Cannot drop function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, function

I have function that I wrote as part of a trigger, but cannot drop the function with `DROP FUNCTION aft_delete();`. Why is this the case?

```
myname=# \df
                           List of functions
 Schema |    Name    | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type   
--------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------
 public | aft_delete | trigger          |                     | trigger
(1 row)

myname=# DROP FUNCTION aft_delete();
ERROR:  could not find tuple for trigger 34119
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the CASCADE keyword to drop the dependent trigger (assuming that is what you want).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropfunction.html